# Youtube Flash embed flickering in Firefox

Tags: css, flash, firefox

I'm having a problem with youtube video embedding;

In some places on my site (like news etc.) video is normally displayed and can be watched, while in others (forum topics mainly) it flickers whenever I mouseover it (making a new HTTP request to YouTube, as I can see in Firebug).

It definitelly has something to do with CSS rendering; when I disable JS nothing changes but disabling CSS causes it to work properly.

Firefox version: 3.6.12
Flash version: 10.1.82.76

The code I'm using for embedding:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="390" height="293" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/pIxVoDNbujM?ft=18">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/pIxVoDNbujM?ft=18"></param>
</object>
```

(to keep it W3 HTML valid, flickering happens with normal embed code as well).

You can see it 'in action' here:
[Youtube embed code flickering in Firefox](http://emag.ba/forum/tema/346/pet-5-svjetskih-cuda#post-4247)

Edit: OMG, it works properly when I'm logged out... Now nothing is clear to me as CSS is the same for users and guests, there are just few minor differences in markup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the elements that followed the embed (same level children of the parent div), there was a non-block-level element (small) with class clearfix (doing a clear:both), which was wrongly interpreted by Firefox.

Putting a `display:block;` on .clearfix did the trick, it's working perfectly now.

Comment: Ah, so it was *my* browser :D

Answer (score 0):

It does work fine for me (Firefox 4 beta), so maybe it's your browser..

I suggest you to use [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) always to embed Flash. It's the best and most compatible way to do it, and maybe you will already get rid of your issue then.